# Is it possible to share a common Neo4j db by two Rails apps, each using Neography?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, neo4j, neography

While using the Neography gem to implement a Neo4j database on a Rails app, it so appears that the database is local to that particular Rails app's embedded Neo4j server. I wish to share a common Neo4j DB between two Rails apps, just the way you could do with a MySQL database through entries into database.yml. Is this impossible while using Neography? If so, what could be my possible alternatives which don't involve JRuby(i.e. using neo4j.rb).

Answer (score 1):

Neography is a wrapper to query a neo4j server through the REST protocol. In that case, you should be able to query from anywhere you want, once you have started the server, even with a simple curl command.

You want especially to uncomment this line in *conf/neo4j-server.properties* if your apps are on 2 different servers :

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Make sure however to protect your database, you can read here how to : http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html